# Как импортировать css-файл?

Tags: css3, css

В корневой папки сайта есть файл style.css, а также папка css, в которой хранятся другие файлы style1.css, style2.css style3.css. Как сделать так, чтоб все изменения в style1, style2 и style3 отображались в style.css.

Я пробовал импортировать адреса - не получается. Вот код style.css:

```
@import url(/css/style1.css);
@import url(/css/style2.css);
@import url(/css/style3.css);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если @import url(css/style.css); ?

Comment: точно, так и надо было